# How do I use jQuery with modernizr?

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I would like to use modernizr to conditionally load polyfills. My code so far is pasted below.

At the moment the code I have successfully loads my support libraries. However, it although jQuery loads, it isn't being picked up by the browser.

If I include a script in the page that requires jQuery, I get the following errors in firebug:

- ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
- ReferenceError: $ is not
  defined

So, How do I use jQuery with modernizr?

Also, how can I get my own scripts to run after jQuery (and whatever other support libraries I require, are loaded?

```
Modernizr.load([

{  // our polyfills first
  test : Modernizr.mq ,
  nope : ['../js/respond.js' ]
},

  'http://vframe/wp-content/themes/vframe/js/jquery-1.7.2.js',
  'http://vframe/wp-content/themes/vframe/js/jquery.form.js',
  'http://vframe/wp-content/themes/vframe/js/jquery.validate.min.js'


]) ;
```

Comment: any place/link where we can see this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315165/modernizr-load-method

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it by loading jquery first then modernizr

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr.load function load the resources asynchronously but execute them in order. In this case response.js is being executed first than jQuery which means if you are using jQuery functions inside of your response.js it will not recognize it. As you know JavaScript interpreted line-by-line.